# How install kmapper?

Tags: python, anaconda, data-analysis

I have installed `kmapper` since command prompt, but when I import `kmapper` in jupyter notebook
is visualized a error: No module named `kmapper`.

What can I do?

I should install `kmapper`, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a Conda version for this in a major Anaconda Cloud channel. Install with `pip`.

```bash
conda create -n my_kmapper_env python pip numpy matplotlib scikit-learn bokeh pillow 

conda activate my_kmapper_env
pip install kmapper
```